# How to store application preferences (iphone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, plist, datasource

I have a list of settings for my application (basically setting which disabled access facilities you require) as seen here:

[image: Icons]

I've not worked out how to do the on/off yet (but that's for later!) - At the moment the text and icons are stored in two arrays:

```
arryTableIconsText =     [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 

    [arryTableIconsText addObject:@"Facilities for partially sighted or blind people"];
    [arryTableIconsText addObject:@"An 'assistance dogs welcome' policy"];
    [arryTableIconsText addObject:@"Disabled access facilities for wheelchair users (with assistance)"];
    ..etc

    arryTableIcons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [arryTableIcons addObject:@"visuallyImpaired_off.png"];
    [arryTableIcons addObject:@"guidedogs_off.png"];
    [arryTableIcons addObject:@"wheelchairassist_off.png"];
    [arryTableIcons addObject:@"walk_off.png"];
    ..etc

    selectedCellIndexes = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] init];
```

However now I come to think about it and now i'm doing this actual page I'm guessing they'll have to come out of a plist or similar? Just to save the value of the On/Off.

What's the best way to save it in the plist? Is the plist the correct way of going about this?

I assume whatever datasource will have iconID | iconImage | iconText | iconState

Is this the correct way of going about this?

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `NSUserDefaults`. This class helps you store and manage your application settings by providing convenient methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can see this [refernce](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Introduction/Introduction.html)